# Terraform merge list of maps

Tags: list, maps, terraform

My input is as below:

> ```
> list_groups = [
>  {
>      dev-api = {
>          envs  = [
>              "dev-eu-1",
>              "dev-eu-2",
>           ]
>          hosts = [
>              "dev-api-eu1",
>              "dev-api-eu2",
>           ]
>       }
>   },
>  {
>      dev-api = {
>          envs  = [
>              "dev-us-1",
>              "dev-us-2",
>           ]
>          hosts = [
>              "dev-api-us1",
>              "dev-api-us2",
>           ]
>       }
>   },
> ]
> ```

I am using merge as below:

> ```
> output "map_groups" {  
>     value = merge(var.list_groups...)
> }
> ```

And the output I get is :

> ```
> map_groups = {
>  dev-api = {
>      envs  = [
>          "dev-us-1",
>          "dev-us-2",
>       ]
>      hosts = [
>          "dev-api-us1",
>          "dev-api-us2",
>       ]
>   }
> }
> ```

But I need the output to be:

> ```
> map_groups = {
>  dev-api = {
>      envs  = [
>          "dev-us-1",
>          "dev-us-2",
>          "dev-eu-1",
>          "dev-eu-2"
>       ]
>      hosts = [
>          "dev-api-us1",
>          "dev-api-us2",
>          "dev-api-eu1",
>          "dev-api-eu2"
>       ]
>   }
> }
> ```

I understand the merge is eating up one of the entries because the key is the same but if it could somehow merge the entries/elements, that'll be great.

Comment: Unfortunately most languages' map/hash/dict `map` function will merge one level deep, and not recursively. You would have to code a custom lambda for this. I threw about ten minutes at it, and I think TF's current DSL is not robust enough to allow coding a deep/recursive map merge. You would need to be able to temporarily assign previous iteration's values, and this could potentially just not be possible in a declarative DSL (e.g. to do this in Puppet you would need a custom Ruby function as it is not possible directly in its DSL either) due to same-scope variable immutability.

Comment: In other words, this would probably be a new Golang-backed function in Terraform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather complex issue. I think you should concentrate on simplifying your input data, rather than trying to come out with some convoluted TF code to post-fix your input data structures.

Nevertheless, the [expansion symbol `...`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments) can be used to solve the issue in terraform.

```
variable "list_groups" {
  default = [
    {
      dev-api = {
        envs  = [
          "dev-eu-1",
          "dev-eu-2",
        ]
        hosts = [
          "dev-api-eu1",
          "dev-api-eu2",
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      dev-api = {
        envs  = [
          "dev-us-1",
          "dev-us-2",
        ]
        hosts = [
          "dev-api-us1",
          "dev-api-us2",
        ]
      }
    },
  ]
}

locals {
  api_names = distinct([for api in var.list_groups: keys(api)[0]])
}

output "test" {  
  value = {
    for key, val in {
      for api_name in local.api_names:
      api_name => {
        envs = flatten([
          for api in var.list_groups:
          api[api_name].envs 
        ])
        hosts = flatten([
          for api in var.list_groups:
          api[api_name].hosts 
        ])
      }... 
    }:
    key => val[0]
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
test = {
  "dev-api" = {
    "envs" = [
      "dev-eu-1",
      "dev-eu-2",
      "dev-us-1",
      "dev-us-2",
    ]
    "hosts" = [
      "dev-api-eu1",
      "dev-api-eu2",
      "dev-api-us1",
      "dev-api-us2",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I understand. I'll refactor my existing data structure. Thanks for your help.